# Angular directive communication in compile phase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, treeview

I have two directives, a parent and a child, I'd like a way to get information from the parent to the child such that the child has that information during its **compile** phase.

Specifically, I have "tree" (parent) and "tree node" (child) directives and I want to modify the template for the tree node (child) based on attributes attached to the tree itself (parent).

For anyone interested, you can see the code on GitHub:

- [Tree](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/master/src/scripts/directives/ivh-treeview.js)
- [Tree Node](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/master/src/scripts/directives/ivh-treeview-node.js)

I'll also point out that the tree node itself is effectively [deferring it's compilation until post link](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/master/src/scripts/services/ivh-treeview-compiler.js), so perhaps that opens some doors.

I'd like to avoid doing any dom traversal in the node (i.e. recursively inspecting parent elements to find an attribute on the tree directive). Also, keep in mind that there may be multiple tree directives on the page and they may need to create new nodes on the fly later on so I don't think I can really get away with e.g. flashing the info temporarily to a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I didn't turn up an idiomatic way to accomplish what I was after. I ended up working around the issue leveraging our (already) modified compile process.

Essentially the idea is to:

- Remove the child element's contents entirely during it's compile phase. In our case this serves to break an otherwise infinitely recursive compilation process and also to defer compilation until we can get a reference to the parent controller to help us modify the child's template.
- The child's `postLink` function get's passed a reference to the parent controller. Use the controller to get information from the parent directive and build a new template for the child. Compile this template and append it to the child.

If anyone has a more elegant alternative I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

In the `compile` phase, or the `pre-link`one (which is done in the descending order, as opposite to the usual `post-link` phase), your child directive will only have knowledge of its own template, which means you cannot avoid to look for a parent tree element.

However you could set some properties to your parent tree scope during its `pre-link` phase and give access to them to your child node directive (either pre or post link, doesn't matter for the child).

For instance in Tree:

```
compile: function() {
  return {
    pre: function(scope, elem) {
      scope.something = doSomethingWith(elem);
    }
  };
}
```

Which you pass to your treenode:

```
 <tree-node tree-data="something"></tree-node>
```

(only if the scope is isolated, otherwise it's accessible right away)

Comment: `pre-link` !== `compile`, these are different phases. I'm not sure if you were trying to imply that they are equivalent. To share info during compilation you could e.g. have the parent directive store something in a service then retrieve it in the child. This doesn't quite work in my case (without something extra...)  but I'm curious how folks have typically solved this.

Comment: No I didn't imply they are the same, I meant "one *or* the other". But indeed I chose to use pre-link for my anser, which is probably what people do when storing stuff in a service as well. Maybe you should explain why exactly need to access the parent template

Comment: I don't need to access the parent template. I want the child to modify its own template based information the parent has. See the second sentence.